# Типы данных laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel

Какой тип данных в миграциях необходимо задать для:

1) INTEGER с перечислением `1,2,3,4`

2) String с перечислением `images/1.jpg,images/2.jpg,images/3.jpg`

В первом случае я буду хранить id записей, во втором случае ссылки на изображения.

Сейчас использую `$table->string();`

Но что-то мне подсказывает что я иду неверной дорогой. Спасибо.

Comment: Хранить данные в БД, разделенные через запятую, является плохой практикой (за редкими исключениями). Добейтесь такого результата, чтобы один ID соответствовал одному или нескольким картинкам. Одно соответствие - одна картинка.

Answer (score -1):

С типами по вашему описанию все нормально, id запишите в primary(). Если сомневаетесь, попробуйте использовать генератор миграций
https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended,
правда он работает только для уже существующих таблиц, но вдруг поможет

Comment: Ответ вообще никак не связан с вопросом.